# How to filter multiple csv files by row on certain column values

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, row, filtering

I'm writing a code where I use csv files that contain reviews from different publications, which is column 3 in the csv files. I have to select the rows where the publication is 'New York Times' or 'Atlantic'. How can I do this for several csv files at the same time?  I loaded my csv files (the data contains 3 files) into a dataframe dictionary.  This is how I loaded my data:

```
filenames = glob('articles*.csv') 

dataframe_dict = {}
for i in filenames:
    dataframe_dict[i] = pd.read_csv(i, sep = ',', header = None)

print(dataframe_dict['articles1.csv'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [dataframe.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
Please note you might need to set headers to `True`.

Try:

```
results = dataframe_dict['articles1.csv'].query(
    'the_header_name == "New York Times" '
    'or the_header_name == "Atlantic"'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some other code you can use, which returns the desired indices as booleans which are then used to constrain the frame.

```
dataframe_dict_filtered_idx = dataframe_dict['articles1.csv'][3] == 'New York Times'
dataframe_dict_filtered_idx2 = dataframe_dict['employeesDetails.csv'][3] == 'Atlantic'

dataframe_dict_filtered = dataframe_dict['articles1.csv'][dataframe_dict_filtered_idx | dataframe_dict_filtered_idx2]
```